# How to get additional_information on sales/order

Tags: magento-1.9, sales-order, payment, payment-gateway

This is my code. I would like to get additional_information on API. 
I'm using getPayment, on this way, I believe that I can define this function there. I don´t know, just looking for some help or something that I can use. I´ll appreciate any help.

```
 /**
 * Retrieve order payment model object
 *
 * @return Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment
 */
public function getPayment()
{
    foreach ($this->getPaymentsCollection() as $payment) {
        if (!$payment->isDeleted()) {
            return $payment;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```